# から usage as "after"

Tags: usage, て-form, time, particle-から

In the simple sentence 電話を掛けてから、友だちうちへ行きます。I want to know how kara is used. It didn't feel like it's meaning is "because" here it is more like "after". I think this translates to " After I make call, then I will go to friend's house ". Could anyone tell me what does the sentence mean. I know translation questions are not entertained on our forum, but this is a not a direct translation question. My confusion is specific. Thanks

Comment: Okay so that question solves it. So should I delete the question ?

Comment: In that case - yes.

Comment: There's no need to delete it just because it's a duplicate.  Duplicates help people find questions :-)